# What are the most highly attended US & International charity bicycle rides?

Tags: charities, group-rides, organized-rides

Yep, it's all right there in the title. Thx!

Comment: Not a dupe - but some of the answers to this question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/outstanding-organized-rides mention charity rides.

Comment: Here's a [directory of charity rides](http://www.bikingbis.com/blog/_WebPages/Charitybicyclerides.html) and a [directory of Gran Fondos](http://www.bikingbis.com/blog/_WebPages/GranFondoBike.html) some of which are fundraising for charity. Both for 2011, mostly US. Maybe somebody wants to pick through and figure out which have most participants.

Comment: A note for trying to find these: typically charity rides follow one of two models. (1) Riders are fundraisers (or "sponsored") typical raising $500-$5000 each in donations from various sources and going on the ride. Often these are long multi-day rides. [AIDS LifeCycle](http://www.aidslifecycle.org/) and [Climate Ride](http://www.climateride.org/) follow that model.(2) is that riders pay $20-$200  to go on the ride themselves. Typically these are one-day events, often with multiple route/length choices. Gran Fondo's like [Levi's Gran Fondo](http://www.levisgranfondo.com/) follow this model.

Comment: That second model (riders pay a more moderate amount) tends to have much higher attendance, even if they raise less money than the riders=fundraisers model.

Comment: Voting to close as this question is starting to produce a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how you would find the individual rides with the highest participation, but there are a few organizations that reach thousands of cyclists across the US by holding rides in several communities.

In the US you tend to rarely see huge rides because the logistics and regulation hoops in many areas is to great to overcome.  Many rides are capped at 2000 or 3000 riders.

The list below is based on my perception that they hold the larger rides in the most areas:

[MS Bike Rides](http://bikems.org) (National Multiple Sclerosis Society): Most are two day rides and many rides attract 3,000 riders or more.

[LIVESTRONG](http://www.livestrong.org/Take-Action/Team-LIVESTRONG-Events/Ride) (Cancer - Lance Armstrong Foundation): In addition to 3-4 of their own large rides, they have begun to sponsor other large ride like RAGBRAI.

[Tour de Cure](http://tour.diabetes.org/site/PageServer?pagename=TC_homepage) (American Diabetes Association) Their site reports that between the 80 or so rides they sponsor they get 40,000 participants.

There are a lot of others like Team in Training, American Lung Association Rides, etc, but those three have charity rides as one of the primary fundraising activities and are fairly well known throughout the US.

Answer (score 2):

The [London to Brighton Bike Ride](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-13829703) organized by the [British Heart Foundation](http://www.bhf.org.uk/get-involved/events/bike-rides.aspx) is the largest UK one, probably the largest in Europe. That has 27,000 participants.

Comment: Also in the UK there is 'SkyRide'.

Comment: Not really - SkyRides (http://www.goskyride.com/) aren't really charitable, but they are rides more geared to families and 'communities' rather than sportive-like, travelling from A-to-B events.

Answer (score 1):

The 2013 Ride For Roswell Park Cancer research hospital drew a reported 9000 riders. The hospital is located in Buffalo New York. Additionally it features a 200 rider peloton the evening before prior to opening ceremonies. The ride winds through the city from the hospital to the University of Buffalo Amherst campus covering 13.5 miles.

Comment: There's no need to write your name at the bottom of the answer: it shows up just there on the right.